# Setting text color on image in react native svg

Tags: react-native

I am trying to find the best approach to set the text color inside an svg which is acting as a background image in react-native.

I have the following code for the background image itself:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
  flex: 1,
  height: null,
  width: null,
  backgroundColor: '#0da651',
  textAlign: 'center'
}
```

However I need to set the background color of the svg but also the color of the text inside it and I am not sure what is the best approach to do this. Having looked at the docs below I can see that Image does not have a color style prop so It would be good to have some thoughts on workarounds for this.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html

Component Render function:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View>
          <SvgUri
            source={require('./assets/images/logo-light.svg')}
            style={styles.container}/>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Please sign in.</Text>
          <Text style={styles.linkStyle}>Forgotten Password</Text>
          <Button
            onPress={this.onSubmitPress}
            title= "Submit"
            style={styles.submit}
          />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: If the text part of the svg? I usually pass the color as prop if I want dynamic colored svg. Maybe you can attach your svg component code?

Comment: thanks-I have updated with the code, however it would seem the bigger problem i am having is that the file is an svg-trying https://github.com/matc4/react-native-svg-uri but no joy as of yet.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `svg-uri`. Maybe try using `react-native-svg` - https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg, and then follow the documentation to rewrite your svg as a RN component. You will have full control on all of the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

import text component from 'react-native-svg' and and wrap SvgUri and Text in Svg add below attributes to the text feild
stroke="white" fill="white"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).